# Firebase - Get last 100 response onValue trigger?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the last 100 response whenever onValue triggers, however I am not sure if using callback method will anyway query for all the results as shown below:

```
onValue(chatRef, (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log('Added child = ', snapshot.val());
            } else console.log('Uhum');
        });
```

In the above snippet, my understanding is that snapshot.val being a synchronous method would have already fetched all the response which can be troublesome for me. However how I want it to be is:

```
onValue(query(chatRef, limitToLast(100)), async (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log('Added child 01 = ', snapshot.val());
            } else console.log('Uhum');
        });
```

My question is will the second call make a difference or performance and resource consumption wise both are the same? And also will the second call ensure that although I am taking last 100 entries but it will be watching all the records that get updated or added?